# "Whiskey in the Jar" - which version is 'canon'?

Tags: history, folk

Of course folksongs have no canon version, but at least in this case two "main", *very* different variants exist:

The depressive one (e.g. Thin Lizzy, our highwayman ends up in prison charged with murder and possibly will be hanged) and the upbeat one (e.g. The Dubliners, our highwayman is ratted out by his girlfriend, maybe his brother in the army will bail him out).

Is there (at least in Ireland) an agreement about the "true" version? (Maybe it is known which version came historically first, but I doubt that either...)

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have answered your question in the first line "folksongs have no canon version", however . . .

In the case of the history of the song versions by Thin Lizzy and The Dubliners, and assuming that 'canon' version is the earliest then the prize must go to The Dubliners who released it on an album in 1967 as opposed to Thin Lizzy who released their version in 1972.

There have as well been other notable artists who released their versions of the song *before* The Dubliners:

- Burl Ives - 1958
- The Highwayman - 1962
- The Seekers - 1964
- Peter, Paul and Mary - 1965

The song has (reportedly) been around since the 17th century and has undoubtedly been through many incarnations.

[Source material - wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whiskey_in_the_Jar)

It's worth noting the song '[House of the rising sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_House_of_the_Rising_Sun)' having similar 'issues'. It was in a collection in the USA in the 1930's and thought to have been based on a traditional English folk song. However, along come [The Animals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Animals) and record a version which makes the song newly popular and could be seen as the 'canon' version.

Comment: THX for the statistics, at least I can check now whether the versions you gave are the "+" or "-" version...